# Create a table from different array size

Tags: javascript, html

I have 5 arrays namely,

```
Col1 = [1];
Col2 = [1,2];
Col3 = [1,2,3];
Col4 = [1,2,3,4];
Col5 = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Is it possible to create a table from these arrays that look like this?

[image]

How can I make a table that will have the column order same as present in the arrays. Also, if I add some data in any of those arrays, the changes should dynamically reflect in the table.

Here is a new example with added another sets of array

[image]

Comment: @adiga sorry just edited my question

Comment: @adiga i know it sounds awkward but after creating the arrays i dont know whats next

Comment: Do you want to generate a html table  (<table></table>) using javascript?

Comment: yes. i want a to generate a table as a final output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var Col1 = [1];
var Col2 = [1, 2];
var Col3 = [1, 2, 3];
var Col4 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
var Col5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
var columns = [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5];

addColumnsToTable(columns);
addColumnsToTable(columns);

function addColumnsToTable(columns) {
  var rowsCount = Math.max.apply(null, columns.map(x => x.length));

  var res = '';
  for (var i = 0; i < rowsCount; i++) {
    var row = '<tr>';
    for (var column of columns)
      row += `<td>${column[i] || ''}</td>`;
    row += '</tr>';
    res += row;
  }

  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML += res;
    
  var head = document.getElementById('head');
  if(!head.innerHTML.trim())
    head.innerHTML = columns.map((x, i) => `<th>Col${i + 1}</th>`).join('');  
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
#head > th{
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr id='head'>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='content'>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: this one really fits to what i need. One more question lets say i will add new sets of array how can I add those arrays next on the last row?

Comment: no sir. what i mean is lets say the table has been create and I want to add a new sets of array how can I add it below of the created rows

Comment: @myownemail, Do you mean, what to do with Col6, Col7?

Comment: @myownemail, check out updated answer, is it what you desire?

Comment: sir another one can I create custom header

Comment: @myownemail, Sure, also you can simply specify styles by `#head > th` selector, look at answer again

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do it - do a nested `forEach` over the array, then create and append rows:

```js
var table = document.getElementById("table");

Col1 = [1];
Col2 = [1, 2];
Col3 = [1, 2, 3];
Col4 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
Col5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

[Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5].forEach((a, i) => {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5].forEach((arr) => {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    if (arr.length) {
      cell.innerText = arr[0];
      arr.shift();
    }
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });
  table.appendChild(row);
});
```

```html
<table id="table" border="1">
  <tr>
    <th>Col 1</th>
    <th>Col 2</th>
    <th>Col 3</th>
    <th>Col 4</th>
    <th>Col 5</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And if you want to create the entire table in JavaScript:

```js
var table = document.createElement("table");
table.setAttribute("border", "1");
table.innerHTML = "<tr><th>Col 1</th><th>Col 2</th><th>Col 3</th><th>Col 4</th><th>Col 5</th></tr>";

Col1 = [1];
Col2 = [1, 2];
Col3 = [1, 2, 3];
Col4 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
Col5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

[Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5].forEach((a, i) => {
  var row = document.createElement("tr");
  [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, Col5].forEach((arr) => {
    var cell = document.createElement("td");
    if (arr.length) {
      cell.innerText = arr[arr.length - 1];
      arr.pop();
    }
    row.appendChild(cell);
  });
  table.appendChild(row);
});

document.body.appendChild(table);
```

Comment: why the data is reverse?

Comment: That's how it was posted in your question.

Comment: sorry for that. make the order same as in the array

Comment: I don't follow - could you edit the question please?

Comment: Fixed @AkhilAravind

Comment: Fixed @myownemail